# How to get an ExchangeUser by email address with Outlook Object Library?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, outlook, exchange-server

I'm currently doing a meeting finder and for that I want to read people's calendars.

I have this snippet to get the manager from the current user, however I want to get the ExchangeUser by their email adress (not the current user itself).

```
Outlook.ExchangeUser manager = oApp.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager();
```

How can I do that?

**Edit:**
This is the code that worked for me (not optimized yet):

```
    private static Outlook.Application _oApp;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _oApp = GetApplicationObject();

        if (_oApp == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to a running Outlook instance or create a new one");
            return;
        }

        Outlook.NameSpace oNamespace = _oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        try
        {
            var user1Recipient = GetUserByEmailAddress("user1@example.tld");
            var user1 = user1Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();

            Console.WriteLine($"{user1.PrimarySmtpAddress}: {user1.Name}");

            try
            {
                Outlook.Folder folder = _oApp.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(user1Recipient, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Outlook.Folder;
                folder.Display();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Could not open {user1.Name}'s calendar!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error {ex}");
        }
        finally
        {
            oNamespace.Logoff();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Outlook.Recipient GetUserByEmailAddress(string email)
    {
        Outlook.Recipient recipient = null;

        try
        {
            Outlook._MailItem mailItem = _oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook._MailItem;

            recipient = mailItem.Recipients.Add(email);

            recipient.Resolve();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }

        return recipient;
    }

    private static Outlook.Application GetApplicationObject()
    {
        Outlook.Application oApp = null;
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Any())
        {
            oApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
        }
        else
        {
            oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace oNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            oNamespace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        }

        return oApp;
    }
```

Comment: [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser)

Comment: @MaciejLos I couldn't translate it to C#

Comment: You can use [online translator](https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/) ;) BTW: VBA/VB.net is pretty easy to convert to C#.  Let me know, if this help.

Comment: @MaciejLos I already tried basically all of them but each is showing errors and do not convert it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this work for you?

In C#:

```
public static Outlook.Recipient GetUserByMail(string mailAddress)
{
    Outlook.Recipient r = null;

    try
    {
        // TO DO: re-use existing application, if possible
        Outlook.Application OL = new Outlook.Application();

        Outlook._MailItem mail = 
           OL.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) 
           as Outlook._MailItem;

        r = mail.Recipients.Add(mailAddress);

        r.Resolve();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    return r;
}
```

In VBA:

```
Function GetUserByMail(mailAddress As String) As Recipient
    Dim myItem As mailItem
    Dim myRecipient As Recipient
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 
    Set myRecipient = myItem.recipients.Add(mailAddress)
    
    myItem.recipients.ResolveAll
    
    Set GetUserByMail = myItem.recipients.item(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
    
ErrHandler:
    Set GetUserByMail = Nothing
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried to rebuild it to C# because I barely know VB. However, some things like ```olMailItem``` don't exist with C#.

Comment: @Steven2105, `olMailItem` is an enumeration. See: [OlItemType enumeration (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olitemtype)

Comment: There is no reason to create a temp item using `CreateItem` - you can use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`.

Comment: Thank you :) Your C# worked for me and with @DmitryStreblechenko's answer, I was able to get the ExchangeUser as well

Answer (score 1):

Pass the email address to `oApp.Session.CreateRecipient`, call `Recipient.Resolve`, then call `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()`. Be prepared to handle nulls and exceptions.

Comment: Thank you :) With @AxelKemper's answer I was able to get the recipient and with you last snippet I was able to get the ExchangeUser as well